# Awesomium position view in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, awesomium

I know this seems silly, but how do I position the view-able area. 
I downloaded the SDK of course and opened the sample in VS, [image: the] sample project is "WinFormsSample" and I can't figure out how to move the viewing area down so to allow a tool strip or whatever. And help on this small announce would be great.

As you can see my tool strip is over the viewing area.

Comment: Are you docking the browser? If so, the toolstrip is probably "On top" of your web page

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the browser's `DockStyle` to none, and then size and position the browser to fill the form. Be sure to leave space at the top for the toolstrip. After that, set the browser's `Anchor` property to `Top`, `Bottom`, `Left`, and `Right`.  That should make the toolstrip not overlap the browser, and still allow it to resize. 
  Hope this helps!

Comment: If you downloaded the SDK and opened the Sample projects, I don't believe its docked. Its also not displayed in design mode. Other wise I would have figured out what to set.